# How to split string to words?

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have some irregular string that I would like to split into words. String can contain multiple spaces and line breaks consecutively.
I.e. String:

```
"Word1     
Word2

Word3 Word4        Word5"
```

Would turn out as:

```
"Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5"
```

Words can contain special characters, but not spaces or linebreaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to replace all whitespace (including line breaks) with one space character, you can use the following;

```
String input = "word0\r\nword1 word2";
//                       | replace all instances of...
//                       |           | ... one or more whitespace (including line breaks)
//                       |           |       ... with a single space 
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

**Output**

```
word0 word1 word2
```

Comment: What does that "\\s+" stand for?

Comment: Continous whitespaces.

Comment: @user3403621 It's a `Pattern` special construct composed of any whitespace (`\\s`), one or more instance greedily matched (`+`). See `Pattern` API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use String.split() api or java.util.strintokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String sentence = "Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5";
        System.out.println(sentence.replace("\\s"," "));
     }
}
```

`\\s` same as `[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]`

**Output:**

> Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5

Comment: I guess you missed question of OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "your string      " +
                "word2       " +
                "word3";

String test = yourString.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String[] array = test.split(" |\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

This could make sense if you have [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) as dependency:

```
String yourString = "Word1 \n" + "Word2 \n"
        + "Word3 Word4               Word5";

String result = Joiner.on(" ").join(
        Splitter.onPattern("\\s+").split(yourString));

System.out.println(result);
```

See explanation of `Splitter`/`Joiner` [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)